# JPA - EntityNotFoundException, however DB data exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have simple "categories" table with 4 records:

```
ID  NAME
1   phones
2   tablets
3   notebooks
4   tvs
```

Domain class:

```
package com.rest.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the following simple JPA repository:

```
    public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {

    }
```

Now, when I attempt

```
categoryRepository.findOne(4)
```

I recieve an EntityNotFoundException:

> 2017-04-11 10:19:28.898 ERROR 16700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.rest.domain.Category with id 4; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.rest.domain.Category with id 4] with root cause

However, the data is present in the DB.

What might be the RC is that previously I have deleted parent entity which has @ManyToOne relationship with my Category entity and I would guess it is marked as deleted from the entityManager:

```
productRepository.delete(productId);
```

What should I do ? Do I need to flush somehow ?

Comment: Why cant you delete this record manually and try it again if you think you have played around with the dependent records

Comment: Post the `Product` entity as well as it might help to identify the issue (cascading etc.)

Answer (score -1):

ensure that hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in your xml hibernate properties configuration

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```